# Kernel in projective space definition

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, terminology, projective-space

This seems to be a very trivial question (just a definition), but I am not able to find an answer on the internet. What is meant by the "kernel in projective space of a linear mapping"? I understand what the kernel is, but I do not understand what it means with the addendum "in projective space." Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Could you please give us some context here? Where did you encounter this phrase?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I asked my friend for lecture notes from a class that he took (I wanted to study the material as a prereq for another class I am taking this fall), and this phrase was in his notes. He didn't know what it meant so I thought I could ask here.

Comment: My best guess, especially if this is from a comp sci class, is that he's talking about the kernel of an affine transformation expressed in [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations)

Comment: Otherwise, it could just be the image of the kernel under the projection map from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb P^{n-1}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}(t)$ is the field of rational functions in $t$, i.e. expressions of the form $f(t)/g(t)$ so that $g(t)\ne 0$ and $f(t),g(t)\in \Bbb{C}[t]$.

Comment: @AlekosRobotis so is $\mathbb{C}(t)$ the same as $\mathbb{Q}[t]$?

Comment: No, $\Bbb{Q}[t]$ is polynomial functions with coefficients in $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: @AlekosRobotis Ah, I see—thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is just summarizing what was said above: given a linear transformation $T:V\to W$ of (say) finite dimensional vector spaces over a field such as $\mathbb{C}$, we know that $\ker T$ is a subspace of $V$, and as such corresponds to a linear subvariety of $\Bbb{P}(V)$ under the projection $\pi:V\to \Bbb{P}(V)$. That is, $\pi(\ker T)\subseteq \Bbb{P}(V)$ could be interpreted as the kernel in projective space.

Comment: Thank you! I am a little confused as to how to expand this to exponentiation. If I have the kernel in the projective space $\mathbb{P}^n(V)$, what changes with $\pi$? Thank you again for all of your help.